# Postgres idle connections - Jobs running using Pentaho

Tags: database, postgresql, pentaho, jobs, pentaho-data-integration

I use Postgresql for my database and jobs are run regularly with the help Carte servers (Pentaho BI tool). Recently, I've realized there are a lot of idle connections to postgresql, preventing the new jobs that I'm creating to connect to the DB. I would like to understand the following:

1) Does each individual job scheduled on Pentaho establish itself as a connection to the Postgres DB or does the entire carte server, as a whole, count as one connection?

2) How do idle jobs pile up (either in general or specific to the case I mentioned)?

Comment: Have you checked your database connection pool settings?

Comment: An "idle" connection is not a problem. A connection that is "idle in transaction" is a problem.